# how to create an id within the embedded document using mongoDB and spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

im trying to set a id within embedded document. in the next level in mongoDB, using spring data.
lets say i have a User document and each user has multiple Session (One-to-many), and i like to get an auto generate and unique id for the sessions. how would I do that?. I have tried to create the below entities for User & Session, but the id at session is always null!, please help

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String emailId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private ArrayList<Session> sessions;
}

public class Session {

    @Id // i like to make this id auto generated and unique
    private String id;
    private String status;
    private String title;
//assume all Args, Getters and setters are exists
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a default behaviour for doing this automatically, you'd need to manually have a logic to fetch & increment some value from db... [An example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mongodb-auto-generated-field). The best is to have a listener as detailed in that link, but still using your manual logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to update this unique id manually for there doesn't seem to be an automated feature doing that in `spring-data-mongodb`.

Something like;

```
public Integer generateUniqueId() {
    Session latestSession = sessionRepository.findTopOrderByIdDesc(); // latest session
    return Optional.ofNullable(latestSession).map(Session::getId).orElse(-1) + 1;
}
```

where unique id is just an incrementing counter...

& set this value to the new `Session` before saving it;

```
newSession.set(generateUniqueId());
sessionRepository.save(newSession);
```

For more details, check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mongodb-auto-generated-field)